# FileNotFoundError: Github Actions Workflow fails when creating directory or file during test

Tags: python, github, pytest, workflow, github-actions

I am using Github Python application workflow for CI. My application creates a folder to store temporary files. It works perfectly when testing on localhost but it will not let me create a new directory in Github actions. I get the below error:

```
@classmethod
def save_files(cls, files: list) -> str:
    """
    saves a list of files in the "files"
    folder in app
    :param files: list of FileStorage objects
    :return: directory name where files saved
    """
    folder = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    folder_path = Path(__file__).parent / "files" / folder
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
    E    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/runner/work/DocumentAnalysisTool/DocumentAnalysisTool/app/files/20200430-235749
```

Here is my workflow pythonapp.yml file:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest
        pytest
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably some parent dir exists locally but not in CI; maybe `files`? Try fixing by using `folder_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: That solved it. Thank you!